# batch file to search folder for dll file names

Tags: batch-file, command, cmd

I need to write a batch file that will search a folder for all dll's, take their name do some processing with such. So for example a folder containing

File1.dll
File2.dll
File3.dll

within C:\temp

should return

File1
File2
File3

I would like to do some further processing then with these filenames.

Any idea how I might do such?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You are going to want to use a FOR command, probably a simple FOR with no options, or else FOR /F with a DIR /B command.

Comment: I have tried lots but cant get the filename on its own outputted. Any ideas/example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for /r %i in (*.dll) do @echo %~ni`

Comment: @amateur - type 'HELP FOR' from a command prompt and read about the FOR variable modifiers at the bottom of the documentation.